# Make a component linkable or not based on the dialog

Tags: aem

I have a component and want to give authors the option in the dialog to add a link path.  If this link path is filled in, then I want the component wrapper to be an `<a>` tag.  If it's not filled in, I want it to remain a `<div>`

```
<div class="section" data-sly-test="${!properties.path}">
    <img src="${properties.icon}" alt="${properties.alt}" />
    <div data-sly-test="${properties.heading}">
        <h2 data-sly-element="${properties.headingSize}">${properties.heading}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="${properties.path}" class="section" data-sly-test="${properties.path}">
    <img src="${properties.icon}" alt="${properties.alt}" />
    <div data-sly-test="${properties.heading}">
        <h2 data-sly-element="${properties.headingSize}">${properties.heading}</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this than creating two separate build outs of the whole component with a data-sly-test switch?  I've struggled on a lot of examples like this where the wrapping tag/div is changed by the dialog. Looking for something similar to how data-sly-element behaves on the `<h2>` within my code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

### Using `data-sly-element` and `data-sly-attribute`

`data-sly-attribute` doesn't add the attribute to the tag if the value of the attribute is empty/null. Hence, it can be used as shown below to replace the anchor tag with a div if the path is unavailable.

```html
<a class="section" data-sly-attribute.href="${properties.path}" data-sly-element="${properties.path ? 'a' : 'div'}">
    <img src="${properties.icon}" alt="${properties.alt}" />
    <div data-sly-test="${properties.heading}">
        <h2 data-sly-element="${properties.headingSize}">${properties.heading}</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

### Using `data-sly-unwrap`

Unwrap only removes the containing tag and doesn't remove all the inner tags. Hence, this can be used as shown below.

```html
<div class="section" data-sly-unwrap="${properties.path}">
    <a href="${properties.path}" class="section" data-sly-unwrap="${!properties.path}">
        <img src="${properties.icon}" alt="${properties.alt}" />
        <div data-sly-test="${properties.heading}">
            <h2 data-sly-element="${properties.headingSize}">${properties.heading}</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

### Using `data-sly-template` and `data-sly-call`

This is similar to what you have initially written, but instead of duplicating the entire inner HTML, it can be moved to a template and called twice.

```html
<div class="section" data-sly-test="${!properties.path}">
    <sly data-sly-call="${tpl}"></sly>
</div>
<a href="${properties.path}" class="section" data-sly-test="${properties.path}">
    <sly data-sly-call="${tpl}"></sly>
</a>

<!--/* The template */-->
<template data-sly-template.tpl="">
    <img src="${properties.icon}" alt="${properties.alt}" />
    <div data-sly-test="${properties.heading}">
        <h2 data-sly-element="${properties.headingSize}">${properties.heading}</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

For more information on HTL Block statements, refer [this official doc](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/block-statements.html).

Comment: Depending on the use case, I would probably go with the template solution. This approach feels more reusable for me especially when the project grows and there are common (design) elements shared between components.